# ToObject динамический класс?

Tags: c#, json.net

Сейчас я конвертирую JSON данные (с АПИ) через **ToObject<>()**. Но сперва я создаю класс-тип и потом уже конвертирую(`ToObject<List<MyClass>>()`).

Вопрос: можно ли без объявления класса сразу динамический конвертировать?
`ToObject<какая_та_лямбда_выражение_описывающие_поля>()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Такие способы есть, но вряд ли они будут хоть кем-то считаться выразительными.

Лучше с JObject или JToken работать напрямую, без ToObject и анонимного типа:

```cs
JToken obj = ...;

string foo = (string)obj["foo"];
int bar = (int)obj["bar"];
```

В качестве альтернативы, если производительность особо не важна, можно использовать `dynamic`:

```cs
dynamic obj = ...;

string foo = (string)obj.foo;
int bar = (int)obj.bar;
```

Comment: Спасибо, JObject, dynamic - это другие варианты. Мне нужно именно конвертация через анонимные классы (динамический, как в Php7) то есть на лету указать типы и названия полей

Comment: @Vfvtnjd зачем вам делать свой код ужасным? Что именно вы пытаетесь упростить?